# Regular Expression Match exact length of digits

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I want to replace an *exact* quantity of consecutive digits in a string, meaning I don't want it to replace occurrences that are part of a longer sequence of digits.

For example:

```
select regexp_replace('filename07_20160723', '[0-9]{2}', '') from dual
```

returns

```
filename_
```

but I want it to return

```
filename_20160723
```

How do I replace only the solitary `'07'` (that has non-digit characters to either side)?

Comment: Well, your regular expression matches _any two digits_. May be you meant to match _two digits before an underscore_, or _two digits after an alpha character_?

Comment: "certain amount" and "exact amount" - can you tell us what they are? Or are they variable (and if so, how are you communicating them "to the query"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because oracle doesn't support look arounds, to replace *exactly* 2 digits (without digits either side), capture non-digits either side and put them back:

```
regexp_replace('filename07_20160723', '(\D)\d\d(\D)', '\1\2')
```

---

Note: As [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/72835306?noredirect=1), the non-digit characters either side are consumed, so they can't participate in another match. This has the following effect:

```
x33y44z -> xy44z not xyz
```

because `'y'` can't participate again to allow a match on the second digit pair.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was asking, I just want to make sure I understand what you did: what exactly does the ([^0-9]) do? Also it seems to work without the '\1\2' what is this for as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly could the ([^0-9])  be replaced with (\D)? Still a bit confused by the '\1\2'

Comment: The requirement is still not clear, but either way this solution is not likely to work, exactly for the reason you gave. REGEXP_REPLACE will replace all occurrences, but due to the "look around" issue, it will not REALLY be all occurrences. This solution will take 'a00bc00d' and return 'abcd', but it will take 'a00b00d' and return 'ab00d'. It is unlikely that the OP wants BOTH these outcomes, regardless of what the requirement is.

Comment: @DUzvalok I thought that oracle didn't support `\d` etc,  but [it does](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix003.htm) (answer updated). `\1\2` means "group1 and group 2" - the groups captured (by brackets) in the match.

Comment: @mathguy given that oracle is too lame to properly support regex, this is the best solution I can think of.

Comment: That is a perfectly reasonable position, I just didn't see that stated in your Answer. There was no warning that the solution may fail in some cases.